# Python beautifulsoup parsing speed improvement

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Currently I have written my first python script in order to loop through some URL's listed in a CSV. over 14,000 links.  I am trying to 1) get all the keyword tags 2) check page status (404 links need to get flagged). 3) convert youtube videos into the embed youtube link ( after maybe going to the webpage getting the keywords and then converting into the embed link )

It is going so slow but I can not figure out a faster way.  I feel like it is the request.get() attribute but I dont know how i can speed it up.  I only need the meta data but is their a way to only get the beginning of the page and not all of it?  How do i make this code better / faster / optimized.

Also when compiling using pyinstaller I receive a collections problem. I feel like I am using python 2 code in python 3..  as i am writing using python 3.5

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import time

linkLocation = r'C:\Users\JCModern\Desktop\content_links.csv'
source_code = ''
myURL = ''
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
newfilename = r'C:\Users\JCModern\Desktop\content_links_and_keywords_' + timestr + '.csv'

with open(newfilename, "w", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(('cmsid', 'filepath', 'metatags', 'pageurl', 'pageurlchange'))
file.close()
with open(linkLocation, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    next(csv_f, None)
    for row in csv_f:
        if len(row) != 0:
            # init variables
            myKeywords = ""
            myTitle = ''
            myURL = ''
            pageUrlChange = ''
            pageStatus = ''
            pageUrl = ''
            myCmsid = (row[0])
            myURL = (row[2])
            if "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" in myURL:
                youtubeurl = myURL.split('/')
                youtubeurl = youtubeurl[4]
                youtubeurl = re.sub(
                    r'\?|\&|\=|re(l=\d+|l)|featur(e=sub|e)|playnext|video(s=\w+|s)|watch|_?((youtu(\.be|be))|fro(m=TL|m)|gdata|player|lis(t=\w+|t)|(inde(x=\w+|x)))_?|(v|vi)=|channel|ytscreeningroom','', youtubeurl)
                myURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + youtubeurl
            try:    
                source_code = requests.get(myURL)
            except Exception:
                with open('errors.txt', 'a', newline='') as file:
                    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
                    writer.writerow((myCmsid, myURL))
                file.close()
            pageStatus = source_code.status_code
            plain_text = source_code.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
            pageStatus = str(pageStatus)
            pageStatus = pageStatus[:1]
            pageStatus = int(pageStatus)
            if pageStatus == 2:
                pageUrlChange = 0
            else:
                pageUrlChange = 1
            if pageStatus == 3:
                pageUrl = source_code.url
            l = soup.findAll("meta", attrs={"name": "keywords"})
            if l is None:
                myKeywords = ""
            else:
                try:
                    myKeywords = l[0]['content']
                except:
                    myKeywords = myKeywords
                myKeywords = myKeywords.replace(', ', '~')
                myKeywords = myKeywords.replace(',', '~')
                myKeywords = myKeywords.replace('(', '')
                myKeywords = myKeywords.replace(')', '')
            if soup.find('title'):
                myTitle = soup.find('title').string
            if "https://www.youtube.com/" in myURL:
                youtubeurl = myURL.split('/')
                youtubeurl = youtubeurl[3]
                youtubeurl = re.sub(r'\?|\&|\=|re(l=\d+|l)|featur(e=sub|e)|playnext|video(s=\w+|s)|watch|_?((youtu(\.be|be))|fro(m=TL|m)|gdata|player|lis(t=\w+|t)|(inde(x=\w+|x)))_?|(v|vi)=|channel|ytscreeningroom','', youtubeurl)
                myURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeurl
#                print(youtubeurl)
            if "https://youtu.be/" in myURL:
                youtubeurl = myURL.split('/')
                youtubeurl = youtubeurl[3]
                youtubeurl = re.sub(
                    r'\?|\&|\=|re(l=\d+|l)|featur(e=sub|e)|playnext|video(s=\w+|s)|watch|_?((youtu(\.be|be))|fro(m=TL|m)|gdata|player|lis(t=\w+|t)|(inde(x=\w+|x)))_?|(v|vi)=|channel|ytscreeningroom','', youtubeurl)
                myURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeurl
#                print(youtubeurl)
#            print((myCmsid, myURL, myKeywords, pageUrl, pageUrlChange))
            with open(newfilename, "a", newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
                writer.writerow((myCmsid, myURL, myKeywords, pageUrl, pageUrlChange))
            file.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: there are two valuable answes below, which i was preparing to write about both. lxml and multiprocessing (in case if you've 2+ cores).

also consider linecache module.

Answer (score 16):

`html.parser` is a pure-python implementation using regular expressions. You really don't want to use it. Install `lxml` and have the parsing done in C code instead (do remember to then use `BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'lxml')`.

You also don't want to keep re-opening your CSV file. Open it *once*, outside your loop, and simply write new rows to the `csv.writer()` object in your loop.

You can't otherwise speed up URL loading, not much. Network speed is always going to be a bottleneck. You could use the *very* low-level [`PyCurl` library](http://pycurl.io/), but I doubt the speedups it can offer are going to have an impact here.

Comment: Arriving late, but what about async requests, using aiohttp for the url querying part ? shouldn't that lead to a convenient speed up as regards the number of links to query ?

Comment: @LucBertin asyncio doesn’t help make The request-response cycle faster, where it helps is when you make requests to a lot of different URLs by letting your computer do *other* work while it waits. If you need to process a lot of URLs, you could be parsing the response of a completed request while waiting for data to arrive for other requests.

Comment: Yes @Martijn, sorry I didn't mean to speed up the request-response cycle, but actually let the computer do other tasks while having sent "numerous" requests. Wouldn't the "free time to work while it waits data" be a generous speed up at the end of the road ?

Comment: @LucBertin: absolutely! I prefer to use `asyncio` for those kinds of tasks, and the speed-ups can be significant.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent suggestion to move to a faster xml parser, this is a good candidate for parallelization via the `multiprocessing` module. I've rearranged your code to do the request/parsing in a worker that can be delegated to a subprocess. The worker returns the row needed to be added to the csv. I added a 0/-1 error code to the front of the returned row so the parent process knows which csv gets the result.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import time
import multiprocessing
import traceback

def grabber(myCmsid, myURL):
    try:
        return grabber_impl(myCmsid, myURL)
    except:
        return (-1, myCmsid, myURL, traceback.format_exc())

def grabber_impl(myCmsid, myURL):
    # init variables
    myKeywords = ""
    myTitle = ''
    myURL = ''
    pageUrlChange = ''
    pageStatus = ''
    pageUrl = ''
    if "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" in myURL:
        youtubeurl = myURL.split('/')
        youtubeurl = youtubeurl[4]
        youtubeurl = re.sub(
            r'\?|\&|\=|re(l=\d+|l)|featur(e=sub|e)|playnext|video(s=\w+|s)|watch|_?((youtu(\.be|be))|fro(m=TL|m)|gdata|player|lis(t=\w+|t)|(inde(x=\w+|x)))_?|(v|vi)=|channel|ytscreeningroom','', youtubeurl)
        myURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + youtubeurl

    source_code = requests.get(myURL)
    pageStatus = source_code.status_code
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
    pageStatus = str(pageStatus)
    pageStatus = pageStatus[:1]
    pageStatus = int(pageStatus)
    if pageStatus == 2:
        pageUrlChange = 0
    else:
        pageUrlChange = 1
    if pageStatus == 3:
        pageUrl = source_code.url
    l = soup.findAll("meta", attrs={"name": "keywords"})
    if l is None:
        myKeywords = ""
    else:
        try:
            myKeywords = l[0]['content']
        except:
            myKeywords = myKeywords
        myKeywords = myKeywords.replace(', ', '~')
        myKeywords = myKeywords.replace(',', '~')
        myKeywords = myKeywords.replace('(', '')
        myKeywords = myKeywords.replace(')', '')
    if soup.find('title'):
        myTitle = soup.find('title').string
    if "https://www.youtube.com/" in myURL:
        youtubeurl = myURL.split('/')
        youtubeurl = youtubeurl[3]
        youtubeurl = re.sub(r'\?|\&|\=|re(l=\d+|l)|featur(e=sub|e)|playnext|video(s=\w+|s)|watch|_?((youtu(\.be|be))|fro(m=TL|m)|gdata|player|lis(t=\w+|t)|(inde(x=\w+|x)))_?|(v|vi)=|channel|ytscreeningroom','', youtubeurl)
        myURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeurl
#                print(youtubeurl)
    if "https://youtu.be/" in myURL:
        youtubeurl = myURL.split('/')
        youtubeurl = youtubeurl[3]
        youtubeurl = re.sub(
            r'\?|\&|\=|re(l=\d+|l)|featur(e=sub|e)|playnext|video(s=\w+|s)|watch|_?((youtu(\.be|be))|fro(m=TL|m)|gdata|player|lis(t=\w+|t)|(inde(x=\w+|x)))_?|(v|vi)=|channel|ytscreeningroom','', youtubeurl)
        myURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeurl
#                print(youtubeurl)
#            print((myCmsid, myURL, myKeywords, pageUrl, pageUrlChange))
    return (0, myCmsid, myURL, myKeywords, pageUrl, pageUrlChange))


linkLocation = r'C:\Users\JCModern\Desktop\content_links.csv'
source_code = ''
myURL = ''
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
newfilename = r'C:\Users\JCModern\Desktop\content_links_and_keywords_' + timestr + '.csv'

with open(linkLocation, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    next(csv_f, None)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

    with open(newfilename, 'a', newline='') as out, open('errors.txt', 'a', newline='') as err:
        writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
        err_writer = csv.writer(err, delimiter=',')
        for result in pool.imap_unordered(grabber, ((row[0], row[2]) for row in csv_f if row), chunksize=1):
            if result[0]:
                writer.writerow(result[1:])
            else:
                print(result[3])
                err_writer.writerow(result[1:3])
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply but this code doesn't seem to actually do anything.  I have left it running for 15 minutes now the error.txt file was created but nothing is in it and the content_links_and_keywords_date.csv file was created but nothing is in it.  I uncommented " print((myCmsid, myURL, myKeywords, pageUrl, pageUrlChange)) " and never returns anything

Comment: I updated the example to have the exception handler cover the entire worker. `Pool.imap_unordered` will reraise execptions in the parent, maybe that was your problem. I see you tried to change the code for a better html parser, ... good idea! but perhaps best done in the question ... this change was just an exampe - since I can't run it I can't test it. One option is a much shorter example we can all run.